# Does Web Speech API have runtime limit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

I tested this in my own environment, but you can see the symptom on Google's example [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html)

When dictating speech, the results will keep coming back for about a minute or two. After that no more `onresult` events will arrive. While no detectable error has happened, and the `onend` event has not fired yet.
Only if I stop dictation and wait for some kind of timeout, I will get the `onend` event.

How can I set the recognition to run for longer periods of time of continuous dictation?

Again, this can be replicated on Google's example [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html), so I don't think its a specific issue with my code

Comment: did you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @MM Tac I stopped dealing with this a while ago.